# Cargar en <select> información de un .SQL - AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, mariadb

Deseo cargar en un `select` del tipo:

```
<tr>
    <td align=right>Provincia:</td><td align=left colspan=3>
    <select name="provincia" id="idprovincia">
        <option value="-">Seleccione una Provincia...
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

las provincias que tengo en el archivo .SQL.
Los datos los recogeré a través del documento "`provincias_exam.php`".

**¿Cómo se carga las provincias en el select mediante una llamada AJAX?**

Código SQL:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 24-11-2016 a las 12:48:17
-- Versión del servidor: 10.0.20-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `u745845519_ajax`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `comunidades`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comunidades` (
  `id_com` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_com` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_com`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `comunidades`
--

INSERT INTO `comunidades` (`id_com`, `nom_com`) VALUES
(1, 'Euskadi'),
(2, 'Galicia'),
(3, 'Catalunya'),
(4, 'Andalucia'),
(5, 'Castilla Leon'),
(6, 'Castilla La MAncha');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `provincias`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `provincias` (
  `id_prov` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_com` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nom_prov` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_prov`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `provincias`
--

INSERT INTO `provincias` (`id_prov`, `id_com`, `nom_prov`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Bizkaia'),
(2, 1, 'Gipuzkoa'),
(3, 1, 'Araba'),
(4, 2, 'A Coruña'),
(5, 2, 'Lugo'),
(6, 2, 'Ourense'),
(7, 2, 'Pontevdra'),
(8, 3, 'Barcelona'),
(9, 3, 'Tarragona'),
(10, 3, 'Lleida'),
(11, 3, 'Girona'),
(12, 4, 'Almeria'),
(13, 4, 'Cadiz'),
(14, 4, 'Cordoba'),
(15, 4, 'Granada'),
(16, 4, 'Huelva'),
(17, 4, 'Jaen'),
(18, 4, 'Malaga'),
(19, 4, 'Sevilla');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Código conexion2.php:

```
<?

$dbserver = "mysql.hostinger.es";
$dbuser = "u745845519_ajax";
$password = "ajaxajax";
$dbname = "u745845519_ajax";


$con = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $password,$dbname);
if(!$con) {
    echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
  }

?>
```

Código provincias_exam.php:

```
<?php
    include("conexion_2.php");


if(!$con) {
    echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
  }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM provincias";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$rowdata=array();
$i=0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            $rowdata[$i]=$row;
            $i++;           
        }
echo json_encode($rowdata);
?>
```

Comment: debes crear una parcial con el código del select y renderizarlo en tu vista después de hacer la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que realizar un get al webservice php y cargar el select con los datos que devuelve, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$.get("conexion_2.php",{},
    function(data, status){
        provincias=data;
        var prov= document.getElementById("idprovincia");
        for(var i=0;i<prov.length;i++){ 
          prov.options[i] = new Option(provincias[i]);
        }
    });
```

Puedes ver mas ejemplos de get y post 
[aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Comment: Con este código lo único que me aparece en el <select> es lo siguiente: "[object HTMLSelectElement]"

Comment: Tenia un error en la linea y cambie prov.options[i] = new Option(prov[i])  por prov.options[i] = new Option(provincias[i]);  tal vez te muestre alguno otro error por como esta cargado el array, tienes que poner los datos que necesitas, lo escribí como una guía para que lo adaptes a lo que quieras.

Comment: Aún así no me funciona, no sé que pasa a mi programa. Con tu código lo único que me muestra el select es "<".

Comment: ¿Alguna ayuda?.

Answer (score -1):

yo lo veo bien el codigo solo te faltaria hacer lo siguiente:

hacer una pagina separada que contenga los provincia
entonces deberias hacer una llamada ajax a esa pagina y haciendo un Append con jquery al select

Creo que hay muchas formas de hacerlo si quieres solo devolver un Json somo veo que estas haciendo tambien podria leer ese Json e ir populando las etiquetas option del mismo con la data devuelta.

La respuesta de mas arriba es muy buena asi lo hago en la actualidad.

Comment: La teoría lo entiendo pero la práctica es donde me cuesta... ¿un ejemplo línea a línea comentado?

Comment: ok dame unos minutos y modificare tu codigo para que funcione

Comment: Con que crees la función es suficiente, ya que al ser una llamada mediante Ajax, pues genero una función en un archivo .js externo y llamo a este archivo .js desde mi .html con <script type="text/javascript" src="miAjax.js"></script>

Comment: lo que necesitas hacer es un select dependiente mediante ajax, para ello debes popular tu primer select y con el evento onChage o en jquery Change envias el ID y optienes los demas opciones

Comment: Sólo quiero cargar las provincias en el select, no quiero añadir eventos onChange ni nada por el estilo. Sólo cargarlas en el select.

Comment: ok ahora bien necesitas que sea por ajax? porque ?

Comment: Si, por AJAX debido a que quiero que se carguen mediante un fichero .php, sino sería imposible.

Comment: El código tenía un error, lo corregí